# How to remove multiple consecutive sequences of consecutive duplicate characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying to preprocess some tweets for an ML project where I am having troubles with two types of strings e.g.
 `str1 = "coooool"` and `str2 = "gooooaaaaaal"`. 
After removing repeated characters, I would like to maintain the word in str1, i.e.
`cleaned_str1 = "cool"` while `cleaned_str2 = "goal"`.

I tried a few approaches that I found but I couldn't get the right output. Could someone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
re.sub(r"(\w)\1+(\w)\2+", r"\1\2", "goooaaaal") # -> goal
re.sub(r"(\w)\1+(\w)\2+", r"\1\2", "coooool") # -> cool
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. my intuition is that, for English, while we have words with repeated characters, two or more consecutive sequences of repeated characters is highly unlikely (if there is any), I would tend to reduce those to just one characters, i.e. "goooaaalll"-->''goal", while those with non-consecutive sequences of repeated characters, I should keep two, "coooool"--> "cool", I am not sure if this is a good generalization. I use regex to remove repeated characters, but not sure how to implement what my idea above.

Comment: def reduce_length(text): pattern=re.compile(r"(.)\1{2,}") return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", text)

Comment: why not use my pattern?

Comment: Thank you very much! this took care of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeDuplicates(S):   
    n = len(S)  
    j = 0

    if (n < 2) : 
        return

    for i in range(n):   
        if (S[j] != S[i]): 
            j += 1
            S[j] = S[i]  
    j += 1
    S = S[:j] 
    return S
```

This was taken directly from [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-consecutive-duplicates-string/).
There is no way for a program to intuitively know that "cool" needs two "o's" as in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. my intuition is that, for English, while we have words with repeated characters, two or more consecutive sequences of repeated characters is highly unlikely (if there is any), I would tend to reduce those to just one characters, i.e. "goooaaalll"-->''goal", while those with non-consecutive sequences of repeated characters, I should keep two, "coooool"--> "cool", I am not sure if this is a good generalization. I use regex to remove repeated characters, but not sure how to implement what my idea above.

Comment: def reduce_length(text): pattern=re.compile(r"(.)\1{2,}") return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", text)